# How to get Hotmail user profile data from PHP?

Tags: php, hotmail

How to get Hotmail user profile data and email ID from PHP?

Is there any API available for the same?

Any help will be appreciable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the code for get hotmail user profile detail

```
<?php
$client_id     = 'Your client id';
$client_secret = 'client secret key';
$redirect_uri  = 'redirect url';
$auth_code     = $_GET["code"];

// get contacts
$fields=array(
'code'=>  urlencode($auth_code),
'client_id'=>  urlencode($client_id),
'client_secret'=>  urlencode($client_secret),
'redirect_uri'=>  urlencode($redirect_uri),
'grant_type'=>  urlencode('authorization_code')
);

$post = '';
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $post .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
$post = rtrim($post,'&');
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,'https://login.live.com/oauth20_token.srf');
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST,5);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$response =  json_decode($result);

$accesstoken = $response->access_token;

$my_url = "https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me?access_token=".$accesstoken;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$my_url);
$myres=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$myxml = json_decode($myres, true);

$myemailid = $myxml['emails']['account'];
$username = $myxml['name'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There no such official API for hotmail/outlook/live services from microsoft.

However you can use RESTful calls using Identity API to get user details.

This might help

[Getting the user's name and profile picture using REST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826534.aspx#name_rest)

[Getting and working with user contact info using REST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826526.aspx#info_rest)